# Can I access my union using the arrow operator (->)?

Tags: c, pointers, unions

I would like to know whether or not I can use the arrow operator in my union and I don't have access to my build environment.

Let's say that I have the following union

```
union max30205_raw_data {
    struct {
        uint8_t lsb;
        uint8_t msb;
    };
    struct {
        uint16_t magnitude_bits:15;
        uint16_t sign_bit:1;
    };
    uint16_t uwrd;
    int16_t swrd;
};
```

I will fill the content of the union in the following way, but I was wondering whether the access to the union member `msb` and `lsb` is correct?

```
int32_t max30205_read_reg16_WithDefUnion(char reg, max30205_raw_data *p_unionRawData) {
    char aux[] = {0,0}
    int32_t error;

    if (reg == MAX30205_REG_TEMPERATURE ||  reg == MAX30205_REG_THYST_LOW_TRIP || reg == MAX30205_REG_TOS_HIGH_TRIP) {

        error = twi_max30205_read(&myMax30205Instance,max30205Address,reg,&aux,sizeof(aux));
        if(error == 0){
            p_unionRawData->msb = aux[0];//IS THIS RIGHT IN C?
            p_unionRawData->lsb = aux[1];//IS THIS RIGHT IN C?
        }
    }   
    return error;
}
```

I will call `max30205_read_reg16_WithDefUnion()`as

```
int16_t max30205MeasureTemperatureWithDefUnion(void) {    
    char regT = MAX30205_REG_TEMPERATURE;

    max30205_raw_data rawTemp;
    rawTemp.msb = 0;
    rawTemp.lsb = 0;
    rawTemp.swrd = 0;

    int16_t temperatureValue = 0;

    if (max30205_read_reg16_WithDefUnion(regT,&rawTemp) ==0)
        temperatureValue = rawTemp.swrd;

    return temperatureValue;
}
```

Comment: Use arrow `->` if you have a pointer to the `union`;  otherwise use dot `.` instead.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler since I have `max30205_raw_data *p_unionRawData` I can make use of arrow operator right?

Comment: If you have a pointer as shown, you need to use `->` (ur, if you like long-winded alternatives that are hard to read and easy to get wrong, then `(*ptr).member` works too — but please do NOT use this circumlocution).

Comment: If you don't have access to your compiler now, _try it when you do_. (There are also online alternatives, such as Coliru.) Our free time is not offered for this purpose.

Comment: Other online compilers: https://ideone.com/, https://tio.run/#c-gcc, https://godbolt.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `->` works with both pointers to structs and pointers to unions.